# Pending Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Paypal IPN request to my callback Pending status.

In my workflow I only save the order after they pass all checking steps as: business email, mc_gross... and the status must be "Completed".

So when I receive a request from Paypal with Pending status, system will not save order into the database.

My question is will Paypal send another request after the order status change to Completed ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when a pending transaction updates to Completed (or Failed, or whatever) you will get an additional IPN with the updated details.