# Paypal pending IPN message not being completed

Tags: php, paypal, callback, paypal-ipn, pending-transition

I was working on a shopping cart in paypal with php, but when paypal is sending payment_status = Pending, I never recieve a callback with completed even though the payment is saying complete on paypal itself (tested on sandbox and live environment).

([Pending Paypal IPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596325/pending-paypal-ipn)) As far as I can read here it should send another callback or is this changed between then and now?

If paypal is not sending any new callback, is there another way to check/recheck to see if that specific payment is complete?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the change on  language encoding in paypal button set it to UTF-8

> Login to your payapl sandbox or live account and make follow the steps
>
> Selling Tools > Paypal Button Language Encoding > More Options > then set  both option from drop down to UTF-8

Comment: How does this help me getting a additional request when the state changes from pending to complete?

Comment: @crasyboy42 Kindly check ipn log file there must be error Invalid IPN because you are sending request in UTF-8 But not receiving the same. try the steps as it happened with me also .

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got this issue too. Just change the http request to curl request and things will work here. I got this issue in the Drupal and have used https://www.drupal.org/project/chr for the same. If you are dealing with core, you need to check https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?env=sandbox. It will definitely work.